# Left-sidebar in the Topbar - Put the left-sidebar in the topbar network-wide

Tags: script, topbar, left-sidebar

## Left-sidebar in the Topbar ( [install](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js) ) <sub><sup>( [GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/blob/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js) )</sup></sub>

On all SE sites where the left-sidebar exists, this userscript moves the left-sidebar into the topbar, regardless of the SE site-specific preference you've set. Effectively, this acts as if you had checked the site-specific "Hide left navigation" preference on every site in the Stack Exchange network.

Basically, if you don't like the left-sidebar this script makes it so that you don't have to go to your preferences on each site that you visit in order to disable it.

## Getting the code

#### [Install](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js) from GitHub

**It's a userscript. Use a [userscript manager](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).**
This is a userscript, so you will want/need [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) (closed source, most widely available), [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) (open source), or other [userscript manager](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

Unfortunately, I can no longer recommend [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey) (open source; Firefox only). I try to make sure that my scripts are compatible with Greasemonkey 4.X (GM4), but it lacks features which some of my scripts use, but, for my scripts, I try to make it that their lack just degrades performance. The change to Greasemonkey 4.X was *required* by Firefox moving to only WebExtensions based add-ons. However, there were significant changes made to Greasemonkey which broke backward compatibility (and there's still a significant lack of functionality). There is no intent to fix backward compatibility. As a result, using Greasemonkey 4.X will result in ongoing issues with older scripts which have not been updated to be used with it. Thus, while I used to strongly recommend Greasemonkey 3.X due to a significantly better security environment (gone in GM4), I recommend against using Greasemonkey 4.X vs. the alternatives.

#### The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Left-sidebar-in-the-Topbar/Left-sidebar_in_the_Topbar.user.js)

Please [file any bugs/feature requests as issues](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/issues/new) there.

### Contact

You can contact me through Stack Exchange comments or chat.

If there are problems with, or feature requests for, this userscript, please [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/issues/new). While GitHub issues are preferred for bugs/feature requests, making sure I get the information (e.g. comments/chat) is sufficient.

### Compatibility Notes

This script should be compatible with at least the most recent release of the following browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Firefox ESR, Firefox for Android, Opera, and Edge. It should also be compatible with other browsers.

### License

Left-sidebar in the Topbar's code is released under the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).